# Changing a certain element of a string into a clickable link using JSTL

Tags: jsp, jstl

I'm attempting to make a Twitter Clone. Right now I'm trying to display any 'hashtags' that the user posts as clickable links. What I'm doing is splitting the string and if the first character begins with the pound sign, to wrap that in an anchor tag. Currently I have the code on the controller, but was wondering if there was a way for me to do this in JSTL right on the views page.

```
        Transmit tmit = tService.findTransmit(usern.getId());
        String post = tmit.getContent().toString();
        String[] split = post.split(" ");
        for (int i = 0; i < split.length; i++) {
            if (split[i].charAt(0) == '#'){
                split[i] = "<a href='/search'>" + split[i] + "</a>";
            }           
        }
        String joined = String.join(" ", split);
```

Would there be a way to do this in JSTL? Currently I'm adding all posts to my model and looping through them all:

```
<c:forEach var="post" items="${posts}">
<c:out value="${post.user.name}"/>
<c:out value="${post.content}" />
</c:forEach>
```

My thoughts are doing my loop on the `${post.content}`, is there a way to achieve that? Any thoughts would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no direct JSTL method/tag to replace your hashTags data with anchored hashtags. But you can define your own JSTL tag which can do this work for you. e.g.

> Create a class which contains a method to replace your hashtag data to
>   anchored tags

```
 public class HashtagFunctions {  

    public static String replaceHashTags(String s) {
          //Use your existing code of replacing hashtags
    }
}
```

> Include this class in a tag library descriptor.

```
<taglib xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee" version="2.0">  

    <tlib-version>1.0</tlib-version>  
    <short-name>myfn</short-name>  
    <uri>http://www.whatever.com/taglib/trlbt</uri>  

    <function>    
        <name>replaceHashTags</name>    
        <function-class>
            qualified.path.of.tld.class.HashtagFunctions
        </function-class>    
        <function-signature>    
            String replaceHashTags(String s)
        </function-signature>  
    </function> 

    <!-- more functions -->

</taglib>
```

> Now use this tag in JSP

```
${myfn:removeTags(${post.content})}
```

Comment: That worked like a charm and is a lot simpler than what I originally had in mind. Thank you!